# Where to paste Google Map Snippet / JavaScript / CSS for WordPress integration

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a working JS Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/50g6vgns/1/

It is not displaying correctly when I paste all the code onto the text area of a WordPress page.

For the external resource to Google's map libary I added this to functions.php

```
add_action('wp_head','my_addition_js');

function my_addition_js() {
    echo '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"/>';
}
```

Pasted the html, css, and javascript into the text/body of the WordPress page, in various orders with various taggings, different themes, which I won't bore you with, because I'm pretty convinced I'm just putting the code in the wrong place. Yes using text not visual.

Where would I paste the code in the fiddle, to make it work in WordPress?

Does what I added to functions.php look ok? Does it matter whether the javascript goes first or last or whether I put the styles in styles.css?

At most I was able to see the template sidebar but no map, but I've switched things around and now not even seeing the template.

Thank you for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS in the fiddle should be saved to a file, for example, `scripts.js`.  If this was in a folder in the theme root called `js` you could enqueue the scripts like so:

```
function add_wp_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'google-maps',
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
        array(),
        null,
        null
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
        array(),
        null,
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_wp_scripts' );
```

The final parameter sets whether the script is loaded in the `<head>` or before the `</body>` tag.  Null will place the script in the `<head>`, and obviously setting the parameter to `true` will put it by the `</body>`.

The script should be fine, as long as the codes good (!) and the Google Map script is loaded in the `<head>`.

See also: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: I have an addition: `'script'` should be dependent on `'google-maps'` so there is no reason to enqueue `'google-maps'` in the header.

Comment: True, as long as you enqueue it before script.js it will work.

Comment: If so, please correct or update your answer to help others too.

Comment: Thanks @MaxYudin. Will try this and report back. Sorry for the delayed response. So it doesn't matter whether the last parameter is null or true for the Google Map Script?

Comment: I tried the above and got a console warning for having no API key. I added my API like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBwRFMrx8py8-fTxdSrHQKRAU0Prg5mio4&callback=initMap and got Google Maps API Error:

js?key=AIzaSyBwRFMrx8py8-fTxdSrHQKRAU0Prg5mio4?callback=initMap:32 Google Maps API error: Google Maps API error: InvalidKeyMapError 

Without the callback it still throws an error. I'd been using that API key for google places service so not sure why it wouldn't work for this. In all cases map still not showing.

Comment: I don't think Google Places and Google maps has the save APIs. See if you need to generate another one.

Comment: it should work without a key though right?

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't need to use an API key for personal use but you do need one for commercial applications.  

Just use: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js

Comment: So my JavaScript seems to be working in that I can get the directions (try pressing "Submit" here: [link]http://roadtripsharing.com/sample-page/)[link], so it must be using the library, right? Any idea why my map still isn't showing? My theme is X Theme from Theme Co, added the js and css [link](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/50g6vgns/1/)[link] into the theme's custom code area and the html into a raw content element in Cornerstone page builder.

Comment: then added 
'code' 
function add_wp_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'google-maps',
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
        array(),
        null,
        null
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_wp_scripts' );
'code'
to functions.php

Comment: It was the CSS for #map. I had set height to 100%. Changing height to 500px made it work.